dotnet core oidc "~/connect/token" does not working when deploy with subsite?
I'm using an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and I applied OpenID Connect for my API.
I used "connect/token" to verify and get token. Everything is fine if I deploy with site (https, of course) but when I deploy my API with subsite like abc.com/subsite/, then the API ~/connect/token look like does not work?
I tried many ways but unsuccessfully, can you please help me?
https://i.sstatic.net/M6bPyg3p.png
I tried many ways like change the API route but it doesn't work for me
